# Pkisetup between Linux and windows machine

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, pki

I have the cacerts and .pem client certificate in my windows.Now I want to do the SSL connection to my host i.e a Linux machine.I am not able to the pkisetup,however when I am using the same cacerts and .pem file on any Linux machine,SSL connection is successful.

Comment: Exception caught while encrypting private key: begin 0,end -1,length 35

Comment: Please don't add additional information in the comments, but amend your original post instead

Comment: From what you have, a cacerts and a .pem client cert, I assume that you want to make an SSL connection to your server that involves 2-way TLS handshake. The handshake protocol is platform-independent, however, the detailed setup varies based on the kind of client you use to connect to your server (whether it is your Java program, or a `curl` command-line call, ...). You have to update your questions with these details so that others can help you.

Comment: @maximus: for curl it further depends on which of about 8 SSL/TLS stacks your _build_ of curl uses. (On Windows 10 in particular, the curl in \windows\system32 uses Schannel, and it doesn't use PEM _or_ P12/PFX files, only cert&keys that have been imported to the Windows store, and AFAICT only the user 'Personal' aka 'My' store.) OP: what program(s) do you use succesfully on Linux, and are you trying the same program(s) on Windows, or if not what are you trying?